# How can remove error message when i re correct my input value?

Tags: jquery, formvalidation-plugin

validate plugin. How to disable showing error message auto validation on keypress after submission for a given element.

```
    $(".myform").validate({
      onfocusout: false,
      onkeyup: false
    });
```

Comment: Please add some code, example, or screenshot as it is not very clear what your problem is.

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: This is done by plugin itself, check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/amwmedia/sw87W/

Comment: you can enable `onfocusout` and `onkeyup` this way form will validated every time and error will automatically removed.

Answer (score 0):

```
              $(".myform").validate({
                    onkeyup: false,
                    focusCleanup: true,
               })
```

When add onkeyup is false and focus cleanup is true. we got expected the solution.